# Objective-C accessing float getters with variable names

Tags: objective-c

Let's say I have an `NSArray` called `myArray` of `NSString`s (`@"a0"`,`@"a1"`,`@"a2"`)

Then in a fast enumeration I loop into my array to build properties according to that NSStrings. I've got a problem accessing that properties.

I'm trying something like that :

```
@property (nonatomic) float a0propertyLow;
@property (nonatomic) float a0propertyHigh;
@property (nonatomic) float a1propertyLow;
@property (nonatomic) float a1propertyHigh;
..
.. etc.


for (NSString *aPos in myArray) {
    NSString *low = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@propertyLow",aPos];
    NSString *high = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@propertyHigh",aPos];
    SEL lowSel = NSSelectorFromString(low);
    SEL highSel = NSSelectorFromString(high);
    if ([self respondsToSelector:lowSel]&&[self respondsToSelector:highSel]) {
        id sumPartOne = [self performSelector:lowSel];
        id sumPartTwo = [self performSelector:highSel];
        float bla = (float)sumPartOne + (float)sumPartTwo;
    }
}
```

I know my code is wrong but I don't know how to make it work.
My problem is that lowSel and highSel are getters which returns `float` but the perform selector method returns `id` which is ok for an object but not for `float`s.

So, how can I access my float getters with variable names ? I'm sure answer must be simple but it seems that my mind is looking for something complicated (and which obviously doesn't work) so I'm asking for help :)

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `performSelector:` to call a method that returns a scalar value. The documentation for `performSelector:` clearly says what you have to do:

> For methods that return anything other than an object, use `NSInvocation`.

An `NSInvocation` is a little more complex to set up but more flexible regarding arguments and return types.

In your case, it is probably easier to use Key-Value Coding instead:

```
[self valueForKey:low];
```

takes the return type into account and will automatically wrap the `float` in an `NSNumber`.

Comment: Of course you're right ! I always forgot that NSObject properties are key value coding compliant. Thanks for your answer (and the NSInvocation part)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use these getter methods, you can change your properties to `double` and use objc_msgSend_fpret():

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <objc/message.h>

double arg0 = objc_msgSend_fpret(self, lowSel);
```

If you can avoid getters (I know, that's not good practice, but anyway, it works for sure with the following method), and use the instance variables directly:

```
void *object_getIvarPtr(id obj, const char *name)
{
    if (!obj || !name)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    Ivar ivar = object_getInstanceVariable(obj, name, NULL);

    if (!ivar)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    return ((char *)obj + ivar_getOffset(ivar));
}

float arg0 = *(float *)object_getIvarPtr(self, [lowSel UTF8String]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at least I learnt about the objc_msgSend_fpret  (+1) which I didn't know about. Nevertheless the answer of Ole is really what solved my case.

Answer (score -1):

One way you can do is convert your floats into objects at runtime such as:-

```
NSString *str=[NSSTring stringWithFormat:@"%f",yourFloatValue];
```

and then u can retrive it using

```
[str floatValue];
```

Comment: This doesn't answer what the OP's question was.

Comment: Rather use NSNumber than NSString.

Comment: Understand that i am asking him to modify the highSel and lowSel methods to pass objects and not where your intuition leads you to see the implementation.So,please consider before simply voting down